# How to convert QT Qimage to java awt Buffered Image?

Tags: qt4

I am trying to convert java qt QImage to BufferedImage using the following code, but it does't work

QImage image = map.toImage();

byte buf[] = image.copyOfBytes();

```
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
    try {
        BufferedImage img = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(in);
              File file = new File("newimage.bmp");
            ImageIO.write(img, "bmp", file);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I did reverse logic with this code and it works:

```
Object o_image = mimeData.imageData();
QImage image = (QImage)o_image;

BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(
    image.width(), image.height(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

for (int x = 0; x < image.width(); ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < image.height(); ++y) {
        bufferedImage.setRGB(x, y, image.pixel(x, y));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.qtjambi.info/Converting_java.awt.Image_to_QImage 
Method on the link above does it the other way around. It converts an Image to a QImage, I'm guessing it shouldn't be too hard to reverse the logic and do it the other way around.

I will however warn you in advance that it isn't exactly fast.. I'll update the page if I find a faster way.